# AS3 - Cannot access a property or method of a null object reference

Tags: actionscript-3

What is wrong about this code that Flash would throw an error at me?

`var list:List = List(DisplayObjectContainer(stage.getChildByName(target1)).getChildByName(target2));`

Don't worry about the `target1` and `target2`, they are Strings. Tell me if my information is short.

I first used `MovieClip` instead of `DisplayObjectContainer`, then a Google on net........

The point here is I dynamically created a `MovieClip` `target1` and statically created a `listbox` `target2` and I want to access the `listbox` from stage.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Possible reasons:

1. `stage` is not accessible within the context of your code.
2. The String you have stored as `target1` does not match the instance name of a child available on the stage (assuming that point 1 is not the case and you can indeed access the stage).
3. Same as point 2 but with `target2`.

You should `trace()` each of those three properties and see which one returns `null`.